# Overlay the big map image with Google Maps API

Tags: image, google-maps-api

I put the image on my website with overlay option in Google Maps API. But the map image which is overlayed is too big: 2.85 MB.

I can't resize it, so I wonder is there an option to put it somewhere on my server, not some tinypic or similar servers because they resize it?

I need direct link to the image.
Coding is:

```
var oldmap = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
          "http://i39.tinypic.com/map.jpg", 
       imageBounds);this:
```

I put tinypic link just for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you taking a look at this link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596597/google-maps-api-v3-custom-tiles